# How to convert image file data in a byte array to a Bitmap?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, bitmap

I want to store image in `SQLite DataBase`. 
I tried to store it using `BLOB` and `String`, in both cases it store the 
image and can retrieve it but when  i convert it to `Bitmap` using 
`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(...)` it return null.

I have used this code, but it returns null

```
Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
```

Comment: Please read the first 5-10 links in the "Related" section on this page.

Comment: Did you encode the bitmap before writing to database?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Just try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/images/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /* Ignored for PNGs */, blob);
byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
```

If `bitmapdata` is the byte array then getting `Bitmap` is done like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length);
```

Returns the decoded `Bitmap`, or `null` if the image could not be decoded.

Comment: image could not be decoded if it is in other format that you are trying to decode from

Comment: What if I need to perform such an operation many times in sequence? Isn't it resource-consuming to create new Bitmap object every time? Can I somehow decode my array into existing bitmap?

Comment: I post a different answer when you just have a buffer of the image pixel. I was getting always null because of the lack of with, height and color in my buffer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 38):

The answer of Uttam didnt work for me. I just got null when I do:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length);
```

In my case, bitmapdata only has the buffer of the pixels, so it is imposible for the function decodeByteArray to guess which the width, the height and the color bits use. So I tried this and it worked:

```
//Create bitmap with width, height, and 4 bytes color (RGBA)    
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bitmapdata);
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html for different color options

Comment: what is mBitmaps?

Comment: @Julian How to byte[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String when retreving image from Sqlite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63658886/android-byte-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-integer?noredirect=1#comment112570298_63658886

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version of Uttam's answer which I used for my app.
The uri can be obtained, for example, using     `registerForActivityResult`
(see [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) answer of Muntashir Akon)

```kotlin
var uri: Uri? = null
var bitmap: Bitmap? = null

// enter the code to get the uri

try {
    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(
        context.contentResolver,
        uri!!
    )
    bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source) { decoder, _, _ ->
        decoder.setTargetSampleSize(1) // shrinking by
        decoder.isMutableRequired = true // this resolve the hardware type of bitmap problem
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```