# How to get a File instance of a drawable?

Tags: android, file, uri, drawable, fileinputstream

Below is the code that I cope with logo printing. The logo is placed in res/drawable folder. When I run the app, it throws:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.resource:/com.android.test/2130837505 (No such file or directory).
```

Any advice?

```
    public  boolean printLogo()
    {
      Uri logo_path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.android.test/" + R.drawable._logo);
      File logo = new File(logo_path.toString());
      byte[] logo_bytes = new byte[(int) logo.length()];
      System.out.print("Length:" + logo.length());
      FileInputStream fs;
      try {
          fs = new FileInputStream(logo);
          fs.read(logo_bytes);
          fs.close();
          mChatService.write(logo_bytes);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: can u explain your problem what u are trying to do?

Comment: I try to print a bitmap via bluetooth-connected printer. `mChatService.write(Byte[] b[])` is where `OutputStream.write(Byte[] b[])` is executed. In that case, I need transfer a bitmap to a byte array. I placed the bitmap in res/drawable folder, and wrote the code above, then I encountered the FileNotFoundException just as I described.

Comment: see Dheeresh answer i think this will help u

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes you should add the resource of such type under assets or raw directory...

but if you `have any limitation` ans you only need byte array can try

```
Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.icon_resource);

  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
   byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: this works but a new problem occurs. With this byteArray, a bunch of unreadable, messy code was printed instead of an the image. The image I tend to print is a PNG, the printer I use is a black white printer. Do you have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: so far as I see, the PNG is black white.

Comment: it's png. the color is just black and white

Comment: it should work ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap

Answer (score 1):

Put your image resources under assets folder first, then can use the `AssetManager` for getting `InputStream` from resource.

```
AssetManager mgr = context.getAssets(); 
FileInputStream fin = (FileInputStream)mgr.open("path/filename");
```

`path` should not contain the assets folder.

Comment: does the 'filename' here include the extension,e.g.,'.png'?

Comment: yes.. e.g. folder structure is `assets>images>new.png` then path will be `images/new.png`