# UIImage equivalent on Android

Tags: android

Is there something equivalent to the UIImage iOS class in Android?  I need an object that can take in a byte array and store it as an image in memory so I can use it later.

Comment: Gotta be [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html), right?  [setImageBitMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap))

Answer (score 1):

You can convert bitmap to byte array and store where you want. Use like that

Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `Bitmap` and `BitmapFactory` Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a different article that answers my question:

[How to convert byte array to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap)

I can use the Bitmap object and create them using BitmapFactory.