# Setting an Android image using a Hex value

Tags: java, android, imageview

Is it possible to set an android Image using the Hex value of a PNG image??

So my code looks something like this:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
String test = intent.getStringExtra(AndroidPoS.MESSAGE_KEY2 + ".PNG"); //MESSAGE_KEY2 contains the hex value for the image
imageView.setImageResource(test);
```

I know this doesnt compile but that gives you a basic idea of what I am trying to achieve. If anyone has any ideas on how to implement this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to somehow convert the hex String to an actual byte array. It is highly probable that this was solved somewhere already. And as soon as you have that array of bytes, let's call it `imagebytes`, you can do this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagebytes, 0, imagebytes.length);
```

You can read about BitmapFactory here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

A similar question was answered here: 
[How to convert byte array to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I already have the byte array but it is converted to a string so I guess I just need to convert it back

Comment: Hey, if you only store it to a String for the Intent, you can store a byte array directly as an extra. Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getByteArrayExtra(java.lang.String)

Comment: Ok thanks - think i have the byte array sorted now, il check to see if this converts to a bmp correctly

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't really give an idea of what you are trying to do. What do you mean by the 'hex value of a png'? A single hex value would account for one pixel in the png

If you mean how do you convert the name of a drawable to its int resource id, for example if you have R.drawable.yourdrawable and you want to find out the int value using "yourdrawable", you can use something like

```
 context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, resType, context.getPackageName());
```

Where name is the name of the file (without extension ex "yourdrawable") and resType is "drawable", "color", "integer" etc

However, you can pass R.drawable.yourdrawable as an Integer extra in the intent. Using the identifier is slower than using the id and is discurraged