# ByteArray to Bitmap gives null

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to convert byte array to bitmap to display an image in android app. But while converting it is returning the null value. I have used the following code:

```
operations = new DataBaseOperations();
byte image[] = operations.fetchimage(); // gets byte array from the database        
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, options);
```

Here`bitmap` is null, why?

Comment: have you got image.length properly.??

Comment: Check whether the image[] is null or not..

Comment: I had the same problem. This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40882445/4539359

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this link. It will solve your problem

[How to convert byte array to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap)

or just check this code

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/images.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
```

//if bitmapdata is the byte array then getting bitmap goes like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
```

Returns The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decode.

Comment: I'm getting null. How to decode it in any other way?? If the image could not be decode. Is it possible??