# sending a customized object to intent android

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I want to pass an object of type `Annonce` to an Intent. As you can see, it's  simple if the class attributes are primitives, However; in my case I have an image (Bitmap) and an attribute of type `Client` ( I have created a `Client` class).
My solution is to access the `Client` attributes (using getter and setter) and parsing it in the `writeToParcel` method one by one (it takes too much time), and for the image, I am sending it in the `mainActivity` using `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Can anyone help me do it all in `Annonce` class.

```
public class Annonce implements Parcelable {

    String article, desc, temps, ville, categorie;
    int prix;
    Bitmap img;
    Client c;

    public Annonce(String article, String desc, String temps, String ville,
            String categorie, int prix, Bitmap img, Client c) {
        this.article = article;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.c = c;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.img = img;
        this.temps = temps;
        this.categorie = categorie;
        this.ville = ville;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Annonce> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Annonce>() {

        public Annonce createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Annonce(source);
        }

        public Annonce[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Annonce[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(article);
        parcel.writeString(desc);
        parcel.writeString(temps);
        parcel.writeString(ville);
        parcel.writeString(categorie);
        parcel.writeInt(prix);
    }

    public Annonce(Parcel source) {
        article = source.readString();
        desc = source.readString();
        temps = source.readString();
        ville = source.readString();
        categorie = source.readString();
        prix = source.readInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a Serializable approach?

Comment: is there any solution with parcelable ?

Comment: In parcelable you can just convert the Client into Object and vice versa. however Bitmap can never be passed.. it should be a byte[] first before going to bitmap

Comment: Just in case, how huge are those bitmaps usually?

Comment: u mean  c= (Client) source.readValue(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

Comment: the bitmap are big , it only work with new smartphone , but using my old phone, it stopped  if i send a hd image .

Comment: parcel.writeValue(Object);

Comment: And in images you have parcel.writeByteArray(); doesnt it? :)

Comment: Tell me if it works Ill build an answer

Comment: This is not even question of "big". AFAIK the *total* size of Binder buffer (which holds all Parcelables in all Binder interactions of your process) is about 1Mb. This means, that as soon, as someone equally "clever" sends you another image or byte array of similarly huge size (but still below 1Mb) your app will choke with TransactionTooLargeException. Don't send Bitmaps over the wire. This is stupid design mistake. Send Uri. Retrive the  bitmap from Uri on other side.

Comment: In serializable approach you may write on the disk for the bitmap.. then read it anywhere

Comment: @Sheychan , it dosn't work, img is bitmap not []bytes

Comment: Yah that is why you should convert it into bytes[] its very possible... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array

Comment: Then when you already need the bitmap convert the byte[] into bitmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap

Comment: I convert it in Annonce class ?

Comment: Don't do it in `Annotate`, do your disk operations in `AsyncTask`. Also please move the extended discussion into the chat. This is not what comments on Stack Overflow are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an attribut of type "bitmap" is not a good solution . Instead of that , we can use the path of the image to refer to the bitmap image . 
Also, we can convert the Client into object in parcelable in order to send it through intent.