# How to convert image file data to a Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

```
 URL imageUrl = new URL("http://192.168.0.103:8080/mm/showImage?id=2&fileName=fesc1cc.JPG&imgType=books" );

        //URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            buffer.append(inputLine);
        in.close();     


        conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        conn.disconnect();
```

How can I convert the data I am receiving to Bitmap and display it in an image view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert byte array to Bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap)

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(myImageData.getBytes());
Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
```

**OR**

```
byte []bt = buffer.toString().getBytes();
Bitmap i = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer.getBytest or buffer.tobytes, 0,bt.length);
```

Comment: the data is in StringBuffer buffer,do I have to convert it to string.@SuhasBachewar

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh you have to write " buffer.toString() " or  directly pass buffer data  as mention in updated answer

Comment: what is bt.length here @SuhasBachewar

Answer (score -1):

you can use picasso library to do this`Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(imageview);`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO.

Answer (score -1):

Use Picasso library instead. Picasso it's very easy to use.
`Picasso.with(context).load("url").into(ImageView)`.
More info here
http://square.github.io/picasso

Answer (score -2):

More efficient way is using Glide. Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.

Usage of library:

- Add below codes to your gradle file (Module:app)

  ```
  repositories {
      mavenCentral() 
  }

  dependencies {
      ...
      compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  }
  ```
- Use glide to load your url image to imageview

  ```
  Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
  ```

For more information please visit https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Good luck.

**EDIT:**

```
Glide.with(this)
.load("http://192.168.0.103:8080/mm/showImage?id=2&fileName=fesc1cc.JPG&imgType=books")
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: do it also convert raw data

Comment: Yes you can load byte array of image with Glide, but i guess you want to load an image from a url? You don't need to open a connection and get stream. Glide can handle this, just give imageUrl and imageview to it.

Comment: I have to send some parameters and get the raw data from URL and then convert it to bitmap @BatuhanCoskun

Comment: Not getting anything in imageView.@BatuhanCoskun