# Android : width and height must be > 0 for recycler view when Converting to Bitmap

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, integer

Stored text and images in Sqlite and trying to retreive the those data's into the recyclerview, and when dispaying the Images into recyclerview it Shows Error  **width and height must be > 0**

while saving the image in sqlite i convert bitmap to byte

databasehelper

```
String query =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                        + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_IMAGE + " BLOB )";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
```

CustumAdapter.java

```
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<String> list_name;
ArrayList<byte[]> list_image ;



public CustomAdapter( Context context
          , ArrayList list_name, ArrayList list_image ){
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list_name = list_name;
    this.list_image =list_image ;

}
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.listname.setText(String.valueOf(list_name.get(position)));
       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(list_image. get (position), 0, list_image. get (position).length);

   ImageView  image = holder.imgname;
   image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_name.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView listname;
        ImageView imgname;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            listname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_name);

           imgname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_list);

        }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String>  title;
    ArrayList<byte[]> image;
    CustomAdapter ca;

          myDB = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        
                title = new ArrayList<>();
                image = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        
                storeDataInArrays();
                ca = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, title,image);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(ca);

    
     void storeDataInArrays(){
            Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
            if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
    
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   
            }else{
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    
                    title.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    image.add(cursor.getBlob(2));
    
                }
               
            }
        }
```

RecyclerView.xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        />
```

logcat

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1055)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1022)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:972)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:892)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:763)
        at com.Karthickyuvan.check.CustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.java:61)
        at com.Karthickyuvan.check.CustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.java:19)
```

Comment: To be able to help you could you please tell us which line in CustomAdapter.java is line 54 and line 17?

Comment: `holder.imgname.setImageResource((Integer) list_image.get(position));`

Comment: while retreving the image it shows error i think  image in database was stored in blob

Comment: Have you tried adding the <String> identifier to the ArrayList? Maybe that helps

Comment: i tried bro if i add ` private ArrayList<String> list_name,list_image ;` then it shows error  **byte[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String**

Comment: i think i want to convert byte to bitmap but i dont know how @Cyb3rKo

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap

Comment: Try taking `cursor.getBlob()` into a new byte array and then push it into the ArrayList.

Comment: @VSSCHAITANYAChavali sry new to Sndroid Cant know to do ? Where i want to use inside the storeDataInArrays() ?

Comment: @Kingg Yes. Try `byte[] b = cursor.getBlob()` And then `image.add(b)`

Comment: i add  `byte[] b = cursor.getBlob(2);

              image.add(b);` and try to run it Shows Error in CustomAdapter in line 17 **byte[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String`**( holder.imgname.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(list_image.get(position)));)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the onBindViewHolder method, you are wrongly converting byte[] to Integer.

You can use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() to perform the decoding from byte[] to bitmap.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(list_image. get (position), 0, list_image. get (position). length);
```

Then use ImageView.setImageBitmap()

```
image = holder.imgname;
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: thanks bro ,   i decare  `ImageView image = holder.imgname; ` when i run the app it shows error **width and height must be > 0**

Comment: @Kingg @Kingg Try simply `image.setImageBitmap(bmp);`

Comment: no bro, it Doesn't work it say expected 4 arguments so i pass  `holder.imgname.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,0,0,false))` Still the same error **width and height must be > 0**

Comment: @Kingg sorry, it was a typo. I updated my comment check again.

Comment: Thanks bro , but Still the Same Error, I Updated the Code Plz Check

Comment: @Kingg No no. Check my comment. Not my answer. Anyway, I'm giving it again. @Kingg @Kingg Try `image.setImageBitmap(bmp);`

Comment: @Kingg Glad I could help. If you found my answer helpful, upvote it and Mark it as correct.

Comment: @Kingg Great. As the change worked, I also updated my answer with that.